How can I find the reduction formula for this integral?
I don´t know how to derive the reduction formula for this integral:
$$\int \frac{1}{x^m\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx$$
I know you have to use integration by parts, but I have tried everything I can come up with and I don´t get anywhere.
These are some of the ones I've tried:
$u=\frac{1}{x^m},\mspace{0.4cm}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},\mspace{0.4cm} \frac{1}{x^{m+1}},\mspace{0.4cm} \frac{1}{x^{m}\sqrt{1-x^2}}$
$dv=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}, \mspace{0.4cm} \frac{1}{x^m}, \mspace{0.4cm}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}, \mspace{0.4cm} 1 $
I just can't find the trick, somebody please help :(

Add and subtract $x^2$ in the numerator, then use integration by parts on one of the terms only.

Denote $I_m$ as the integral in the problem. Substitute $\sqrt{1-x^2} = u$, then  $\frac{dx}{du} = -\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$ and the integral can be simplified as $$ I_m = -\int\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}du \overset{u = \sin{t}}{=} -\int(\sec{t})^mdt.$$ This is simply the reuction formula of $\sec$, which can be found here.

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Add and subtract $x^2$ in the numerator
$$I_m \equiv \int\frac{1-x^2+x^2}{x^m\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^m}dx + \int\frac{1}{x^{m-2}\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
Then use integration by parts only on the first term.
